Simulate VK_DOWN through serial port java
I need to press key down (x) amount of times. I'm using JSSC which writes directly to the serial port, meaning I can't use a robot.
When doing serialPort.writeInt(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);, JSSC interprets this as a bracket '('. KP_DOWN also interprets this as gibberish.
Is there something i'm missing?

Using writeInt with ASCII (40) produces the same result. I have been on this problem for about a month, someone pls help :(
